# Wait for Meteor.call result on Client

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to JavaScript.I am not understanding how to wait for a result of an Meteor.call method.
    This is my code

```
     //client/main.js
     //Added the callback
        Template.hello.events({
  'click button'(event, instance) {
    // increment the counter when button is clicked
    instance.counter.set(instance.counter.get() + 1);
    var res = Meteor.call("callMeLater","sanj",function (err,res) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("this is the result main ", res);
      }
    });
    console.log("this is the result ", res);
  }
        //server/main.js
        Meteor.methods({
        callMeLater :function (name) {
            var callMeLaterSync =Meteor.wrapAsync(callMeLaterAsync);
            var result = callMeLaterSync(name);
            console.log("this is the test", result);
            return result;
        }
    });


    var callMeLaterAsync = function (name,cb) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            cb && cb (null ,"hey there, "+name);
        },2000);
    };
```

On the console, i get

```
this is the result  undefined

this is the result main  hey there, sanj
```

How do i wait for the result of Meteor.call by blocking the execution at the client.
Please help

Thanks

Comment: You don't want to (and cannot?) block on the client. Anything that needs to be executed after the Meteor.call needs to go in the call back function (i.e. where you are doing `console.log("this is the result main ", res);`

Comment: So i use Session or Reactive-var?so that the received result is reflected.Is this is the best solution?

Comment: I think you may be confused. The two "res" variables in your code are completely separate. You can only handle the "res" in the Meteor.call callback function (i.e. where you are doing `console.log("this is the result main ", res);`. You can store that res however you'd like (in a session var or reactive var, or just a typical js var. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: yea i am clear with two "res" variables.I am using it for SemanticUi Form Validation.I check whether the entered username(while logging in) is existing in the users collection.Put a red flag if the user is not found.I am not seeing perfect reactivity using Session Var.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show that code so I can see what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code into a callback method.

```
   Meteor.call('callMeLater',"sanj", function(err, res){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("this is the result ", res);
    }
  });
```